# Apple Table View multiline text should be tailed like in the last line for every line

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have the Problem that in my Table View with multilines always only the last line is tailed with ... at the end. The first and the second line contain a very long string without spaces and the should also tailed at the end of the line. For example the strings look like this "Howareyouandwhatsyourname". At the moment they are displayed "Howareyouandwhats" next line "yourname". This are my settings for my cell:

```
cell.textLabel.text = inputText; 
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 3;
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
```

Need your Help, thanks a lot

Martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe would be most easily accomplished by using 2 labels and setting each 'line' of text into a separate label so that it can be truncated there. None of the standard truncation schemes will do what you want (IIRC).

Comment: so I do have to implement a custom row?

Comment: Yes. The standard cell only has 2 labels with different fonts / sizes.